# Using Input widgets For calculations , Bonitasoft

Tags: widget, bonita

How can i do this

i followed this tutorial 
https://community.bonitasoft.com/questions-and-answers/computed-fields-ui-designer

i have been able to create a custom widget for calculations works fine , but i want to have the same like thing in an input widget (Have the two input widgets use something like a javascript expression to calculate)
It should calculate and give the results in a third input box (Editbox)

I am using the UI Designer and my screen looks like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually to do some computation you simply need to declare a form variable with the value initialized using JavaScript. This JavaScript can access the others form variables (variables bind with your form widgets "value" property), do the math and update other form variables.